# My server is not opening on local IP and working very slow on Proxy when i am enable proxy in my browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, dns, server

From previous 2 days i am facing a strange issue. The issue occurred when i uploaded my site to live server and now after that my server is not opening on local IP of my PC. And when i am enable the proxy in my browser its start working.
I was think that this could be a problem of my project but even i delete all of my project which i was uploaded but server still giving me the issue.
I am very confuse and in tension with this issue now because the site should work as soon as possible because the client is waiting.
I am sending the screenshot which i am facing. The page start loading and load for 1 to 2 minutes and then it give this error.

[image]

Comment: check access and error logs

Comment: what access log does in domain? i am not clear on this. Is this from hosting provider? and how i will know if the problem is within access log?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set your base_url in config.php `$config['base_url] = 'http://www.example.com/';`

Comment: yes that is already set. The issue is my domain also not opening without proxy. It opens when i enable proxy in my browser

Comment: Are you able to access other sites without proxy?